# Limitar fecha y hora <input type="datatime-local">

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, php7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que en la fecha solo este activado de lunes a sábado y si estoy en el día miércoles los días anteriores aparezcan desactivados.
En la hora me aparezca desde las 8:00am hasta las 17:30, que el minutero solo se vea 0, 15, 30, 45.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ask] editar y mostrar que llevas pues de otro modo tu pregunta quedará cerrada

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es una pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los inputs nativos de tipo `date`, `time`, `datetime` son bastante restrictivos al momento de personalizar los requerimientos de la seleccion que necesita el usuario; ya que cada navegador puede renderizar el input de manera diferente, no hay un estandar para implementar esas condiciones.

Cuando mucho aceptan una fecha minima y una fecha maxima, al igual que un attributo `step` para determinar cuantos dias avanzar cuando usas tu teclado.

En realidad para implementar las condiciones de tu caso, es necesario que crees tu propio Datepicker o utilizar alguna libreria existente.

Aqui puedes leer mas informacion sobre este tipo de input:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, voy a intentarlo con la librería DatePicker, tal vez conoces algún tutorial donde me pueda guiar.

Comment: Estoy revisando que datePicker https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html  solo funciona con fechas, necesito algo que también funcione con la hora.

Comment: Si utilizas jQuery esta puede ser una opcion: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: muchas gracias, pero opte por usar, https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ esta súper bueno y elegante.

Comment: @AndresOrtega deberias tomar en cuenta la version de Bootstrap, si estas usando Bootstrap 4 ese datetimepicker puede darte problemas

Comment: @Ivan95, me imagino que te refieres al diseño, en este momento lo estoy probando y te cuento como me fue.

Comment: @AndresOrtega no no, me refiero al framework que uses, si estas utilizando Bootstrap como framework CSS, necesitas que tu version de Bootstrap y la version del Datepicker que escojas sea la misma. El datepicker que mostraste es para Bootstrap 3, pero la version mas actual es la version 4